# How to allow user to chose it's own implementation of task Action using Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle, action, task

Part of the users for my system can create ,add plugins, classes etc. .

*To simplify my question:*

I want to make plugin in which there is a task called **checkText** in which on a text file user do some checks but I don't want these checks to be static,I want if user decide to do something else different from the things which the plugins gives him, to define new actions which to replace the action of checkText.

If in my plugin checkText task ,check for sentences which end with semicolons ,user can decided to search for `<h1>` tags and display their content or what ever he wants.
But this work which he create to be keep in the system for reuse in the future.

`checkText{ 
   class = Headings.groovy 
}`

In simple words I want user to write a class Headings.groovy or Semicolon.groovy. And to device which implementation to use, which will do his work.

I am wondering what is the best way to do this. User to write its own custom task and to create a task from this type and to depends on task 'checkText' and in this way to extend the plugin capabilities, or something else.

Comment: The way [the codenarc plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/codenarc_plugin.html) does it is to have a separate xml file describing which tests you want to run.  Maybe you could check for a groovy dsl file (or similar) in `conig/whatever` that describes the custom plugins, and executes it if it exists?

Comment: So you offer to put in `conf/whatever` groovy actions which to be chosen by user and if want one action to choose *action1.groovy* if another *action2.groovy*? Is that possible to do in Gradle Custom Tasks?